# What is the least number of weight trials to identify the counterfeit?

Tags: combinatorics

> It is known that there is one counterfeit coin in a collection of $n$ similar coins. What is the least number of weight trials to identify the counterfeit?

My books solution basically says, in each weight trial the coins are divided into three groups, two of which  are placed on each of the two pans, and the third being the unweighed group. If with an equal number of coins on each pan the scale balances, then, of course, the counterfeit is in the third group. If the pans are out of balance, we know that the counterfeit is on one of the pans, although a prior knowledge as to whether the counterfeit is lighter or heaver than the rest is needed to tell us on  which of the two pans it lies.

The solution then goes on to prove that keep dividing into $3$ will produce the minimum. My question is why didn't they consider the case of breaking up the coins into $4$ groups or more? Also are they assuming we know if the counterfeit coin is lighter or heavier than the others.

The full solution is below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbDIS.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9ItM.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YZg6.png

Comment: If we divide the coins into 4 groups, then weigh 2 of them (groups 1 and 2, for instance) how can we distinguish between groups 3 and 4? We'd have to use more weighings.

Comment: @DylanSp Yes, but we have less coins in each group so maybe we will still get less weighings?

Comment: What I'm saying is that dividing into 4 groups and performing one weighing doesn't provide any additional information beyond dividing into 3 groups.

Comment: But we have less coins in each group, right?

Comment: Not in the worst case, which is what we're concerned about, since we're trying to find a lower bound.

Comment: I am just confused. You seem to be assuming that taking $3$ groups at a time will give the minimum. If it does, can you prove it?